# Install FME Server on 2 nodes sharing the same FME Flow System Share and FME Flow Database (PostgreSQL SQL DB)

Tags: installation, fme-form, fme-flow

Is it valid to install FME Server (version 2023.1 Build 23619 x64) on 2 nodes (2 separate express installs) with both the nodes sharing the same FME Flow System Share and FME Flow Database (PostgreSQL SQL DB)?

Both the nodes sharing the same FME Flow System Share and FME Flow Database (PostgreSQL SQL DB) which are on a shared network drive. The two express installs have independent URLs. So, in this scenario, there is no real fault tolerance from load balancer but if one node fails, the FME clients can change the URL to point to the second node's URL

Comment: you can do this but the recommended way is for FME Flow Recommended 2-tier Architecture https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Flow/AdminGuide/Distributing-FME-Flow-Components.htm read the admin guide carefully. 1 database can be used if you can communicate on the same subnet/firewall and open ports. Note FME Flow 2023.1.1.1 (Authentication Bypass Vulnerability fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but - as noted - it's not the best setup. You have two separate installations with no knowledge of each other. The official method with a load-balancer is better because your users don't need to know about the separate servers and because the load-balancing capabilities might be useful.

If you're thinking about doing this to keep two sets of users separate in some way, for a kind of manual load-balance, then I think you may as well have one server but use different queues, maybe with distributed engines.

If you have a specific reason or goal in mind then let us know. Otherwise, yes, you could, but need to think about whether you should!